# Symfony2 different image validation

Tags: php, image, validation, symfony, constraints

at first - sorry for my bad english :-)

i am new on symfony and i got a problem with the image validation. i save all images in my project in one table. but i need different validation for profile images, news images etc.

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Image", cascade={"persist"})
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="teaser_right", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $teaserRight;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Image", cascade={"persist"})
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="teaser_left", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $teaserLeft;
```

In the target entity i cannot do the following because different images need to different validate

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(name="file", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
 * @Assert\Image(
 *     minWidth = 350,
 *     minHeight = 350
 * )
 */
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I think you need [Validation Groups](http://symfony.com/doc/current/validation/groups.html) so you can add specific image validation to target entity for each group: `profile`, `news` etc.

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(name="file", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
 * @Assert\Image(
 *     minWidth = 350,
 *     minHeight = 350,
 *     groups = {"profile"}
 * )
 */
```

Comment: This is what you're after.

Answer (score 0):

#### You can add validation constrains to form itself

This way you will have complete control of what each form allow. I guess you have separate forms for different images anyway

```
$formBuilder->add('uploadedFiles', ImageType::class, [
    'required' => false,
    'multiple' => true,
    'constraints' => [
        new \Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\Image([ /** options here **/])
    ]
]);
```

Comment: Thanks, that was what i am looking for

Comment: i dont think this is the best solution, validation groups does what you want.